# matchstr not matching regex in vimscript

Tags: regex, vim

The following vimscript code is inside of a function and is not coming up with a match, and I don't understand why.

```
let curLine= '[exec] setup/src/LinkedList.cs(6,15): warning CS0659:'
echo curLine
let matchs= matchstr(curLine,'[(][0-9]+[,][0-9]+[)]')
if matchs == ''
    echo 'no match'
    return
endif
echo 'match found'
```

When I run the function inside Vim 'no match' is echoed. What am I doing wrong? I tried testing this regex using http://regexpal.com/ and it seems to work the way I expect (The parentheses with line and character number inside are highlighted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

should be in this way:

```
let matchs= matchstr(curLine,'[(][0-9]\+[,][0-9]\+[)]')
```

> The matching is always      done like 'magic' is set and 'cpoptions' is
> empty.

Because it matches like "magic", we need to escape the `+` in the regex to give it special meaning. For more details regarding `magic` you can read `:h magic`.

Comment: This answer is not at all clear to me. What in this line makes the regular expression work? Are there any sources I can use to find a way to create my own expressions?

Comment: @Joeytje50 you can compare it to the line in OP's question, also I've added the quoted doc line. Your comment looks like a question. I don't think it is proper if you downvoted an accepted answer because you've got a question for the answer. Downvoting is fine, however, as the one who answered the question, I would learn new things from the downvoting.

Comment: In my opinion, this answer is very hard to use for anyone other than the OP. All you've done is change `+` to `\+`, but you don't explain why this is needed, and how this turns it into a working regular expression. You don't link to the docs where you obtained that quoted line from. Quoting something without attribution to the source is worth just as much as something you say yourself. Also, this quote is entirely without the context of the docs: what is 'magic'? What is 'cpoptions'? I'd be happy to turn my downvote into an upvote if you improve your answer to address these issues.

Comment: PS: I'm not downvoting just because I've "got a question for the answer". I don't think this answer is a good answer for any further googlers at all (because of the reasons mentioned in my previous comment), which is why I wanted to make this clear through my voting. If I would be posting a different question on SO, it would be marked as a duplicate of this, because the question on 'how to use regex to match something with `matchstr()`' is already asked here. That's why I feel like there needs to be a better answer on this question, hence my downvote.

Comment: @Joeytje50 I do explain "why this is needed". I referenced the doc also fixed OP's mistake. When we talk about `magic`  in vim, It's a pretty fundamental term.  If I explained `magic` in answer, should I explain `very magic`, `nomagic`? I cannot explain all keywords mentioned in an answer, otherwise, I am writing the whole vim doc. If someone comes to this answer, and the `magic` is new to him, he could ask in comment, or better, do a `:h magic` in vim.

Comment: @Joeytje50 For example, an answer mentioned "regex", you don't understand what's "regex", you can, of course, think the answer is not helpful so downvote it. And keep looking for a "good" answer, IMO, this is not a good way to learn things.  You should ask or search "regex". Perhaps I'm telling too much here, but anyway, I appreciate your explanation of the downvote.

Comment: I fully disagree with you. I've been using vim itself for a few years now and I've never run into `magic` at all. So a very short description, reference to further reading, or example of what this 'magic' is would help clarify your answer. My point about citing your quoted source also still fully stands. Also you do not explain why this change is needed. You simply quote contextless docs; I don't consider that an explanation. Also, fixing OP's mistake is not helpful to googlers. You're giving OP a fish, without teaching them how to get fish for themselves, to reference the old saying.

Comment: One more thing: if I go by the list on https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/246052 I see that you only did the things listed under the second and the last bullet point.

Comment: @Joeytje50 I think a discussion like this won't come to a result. "you do not explain why this change is needed." I really did. The change is needed since it matches in the "magic" way. You also said you have several years' experience with vim. Have you used `:s` cmd? I guess yes, right? Have you ever asked yourself, why you need to escape some chars when you wrote regex pattern? like `|,+,(`? or you just asked someone for a working solution without understanding it? well, if one ever touched vim-regex, "magic" is a must to know. I understand your point and accept this downvote, it's fine.

Comment: I personally find it a bit hypocritical of you to now ask me if I "asked someone for a working solution without understanding it" while all I'm trying to do here is understand your answer, and you're not editing your answer to make it possible for me to understand this based on your answer. Initially I decided I'll just fix my problem some other way, but just to give an example of how to actually create a good answer on this site, I'll write up another answer to this question to give you a demonstration.

Comment: I don't know what should I do to the answer, I meant the edit, just adding `:h magic` and `:h  cpoptions` ?  IMO, I think it's redundant. If one doesn't understand what are those options, he can find it by `:h` cmd. Or I should explain what does `:h` do in each vim answer in case someone doesn't know about the `:h` cmd? @Joeytje50  let's forget about the downvote. Seriously, vim has a really good doc. If we don't understand something like "foo", `:h foo` usually is really helpful.

Comment: @Joeytje50 Anyway, I updated the answer. I hope it looks better now.

Comment: It does slightly better, yes. I do still think the answer I just posted would be a better example of a good answer to this question, which would help not just the OP but also further googlers who are wondering what's causing this stuff. Probably people who end up on this question haven't heard of 'magic' before, and probably never did very complex `:s` replacements in vim (I use `sed` for the more complex find/replacements). Otherwise, if you know about 'magic', you probably don't need this post in the first place. So, I feel a short 'magic' explanation is in place, as I've done in my answer.

Comment: @Joeytje50 thank you. BTW, something irrelevant, sed by default uses `BRE,` `+` should be escaped too. The vim-regex is much more powerful than BRE and ERE, in some cases, it's even more convenient than PCRE. Particularly for complex scenarios. It's worth learning. Of course it's just for vim users.

Answer (score 3):

Even though this answer was originally answered by Kent, which fixed the issue for the OP, I myself was severely dissatisfied by his answer due to reasons I mention in comments under his answer. So, here's my take on an actual explanation of what to do in this case.

---

The problem with your match pattern is that your `+` quantifier is not interpreted as a quantifier, because the "magic mode" does not by default interpret these as special characters. This can be fixed by either setting the magic mode to 'very magic', which makes it behave like you describe in your question, or by prefixing any special characters listed in `:help magic` with the necessary backslashes. Not listed there are ranges like you're  using here to select for `[0-9]`. Those only work in either 'magic' or 'very magic' modes.

Considering you're in regular 'magic' mode, you need to escape your quantifiers, and you don't need to do anything to special characters other than those in `$.*~[]`. This means your code would most efficiently be as follows:

```
let matchs= matchstr(curLine,'([0-9]\+,[0-9]\+)')
```

Here I've changed `[(]`, `[,]` and `[)]` to their respective plain text characters for brevity, because in regular 'magic mode' they require no special way of escaping.  I've also escaped the `+` in order to have it interpreted as a quantifier, which is the same Kent did in the other answer on this question.

Another way to make your expression work exactly as you are asking for, would be to prefix the expression with `\v`. This turns your pattern into 'very magic' mode, which acts just like you are probably expecting it to in your question:

```
let matchs= matchstr(curLine,'\v[(][0-9]+[,][0-9]+[)]')
```

Or in a shorter syntax, by escaping the brackets with a backslash instead of a group, and not escaping the comma (since it is not a special character):

```
let matchs= matchstr(curLine,'\v\([0-9]+,[0-9]+\)')
```

Any of these three lines would fix your problems.

Again, for a full list of characters that do or do not need escaping in specific 'magic' modes, see `:help magic`. You can also check out https://andrewra.dev/2011/05/08/vim-regexes/ for a blog that explains several of these concepts.